# modules are randomly disabled once in a while

Tags: configuration

I've got really weird situation at one site: modules at /app/etc/modules are randomly disabled once in a few days. Every time something else. Simply 'true' is replaced by 'false' at XML files. Nobody is supposed to touch this site (it's in development yet).

I've changed FTP password, admin password, etc. Still happens.

I didn't find any mention of such issue at the net. What could it be?

Comment: There is nothing in Magento which can do changes directly in files. Please check file updated date when this happens again. You will get idea when it was updated.

Comment: Hello Shaine, if you are using git for development. You can put your config file in GIT ignore. It can be an issue.

Comment: File date is changed accordingly, I've checked. But I don't have any file monitoring there...

Comment: I don't use git there